# What you can do with XSS attacks

Tags: xss

I am practicing in a website which is vulnerable to XSS so as to learn better this kind of attacks. I have managed to inject somewhere the usual `<script>alert('XSS')</script>` and it seems to work fine. Apart from that what else can I do? Could I for example completely deface the website? If so, how can I do that? Is it possible to write my own file and make the website executes my code to deface it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How dangerous is XSS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/206520/how-dangerous-is-xss)

Comment: I have seen this post, thanks for your answer. My question is more about how exactly can I do all these stuff. I mean, what code do I need and how to inject it to make all these attacks work?

Comment: @Walker18: the linked question answers what you are asking in your question. What you state in your comment *"how exactly can I do all these stuff"* is not what you are asking in your question. And it would be way too broad since it can be very complex and depends a lot on the specifics of the attacked website. There are various deep technical descriptions on the internet about specific XSS attacks against specific websites, though these are often more advanced reading material.